# Java RSA encrypted AES key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I have an RSA private key that I am trying to decrypt another files contents that has an AES key in it. So far all I can seem to get to return from the processes is jargon. Not really sure what I am doing wrong in the below code. I have looked on google and have seen this done at least a 100 different ways.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class RsaEncryption {
    private Cipher _pkCipher;

    public RsaEncryption() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        // create RSA public key cipher
        _pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    }

    public String loadKey(File in, String privateKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, Exception {
        privateKey = privateKey.replaceAll("-+.*?-+", "");
        byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKey);

        // create private key
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPrivateKey pk = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        // read AES key
        _pkCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
        byte[] encryptedBytes       = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(in);
        ByteArrayInputStream fileIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedBytes);
        CipherInputStream cis       = new CipherInputStream(fileIn, _pkCipher);
        DataInputStream dis         = new DataInputStream(cis);
        byte[] decryptedData        = new byte[32];
        dis.read(decryptedData);
        String key = new String(decryptedData);
        return key;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**New way with bouncy castles pem converter still not working**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

public class RsaEncryption {
    private Cipher _pkCipher;
    private RSAPrivateKey _PrivateKey;
    private RSAPublicKey  _PublicKey;

    public RsaEncryption(String privateKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        loadKey(privateKey);
        // create RSA public key cipher
        _pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
    }

    private void loadKey(String privateKey) throws IOException {
        PEMParser pemParser          = new PEMParser(new StringReader(privateKey));
        PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair        = (PEMKeyPair) pemParser.readObject();
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair keyPair              = converter.getKeyPair(pemKeyPair);
        _PrivateKey                  = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        _PublicKey                   = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        pemParser.close();
    }

    public String decrypt(File in) throws GeneralSecurityException , IOException{
        _pkCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _PrivateKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(in);
        String key = new String(_pkCipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes));
        System.out.println(key);
        return key;
    }


    public RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() { return _PrivateKey; }
    public RSAPublicKey getPublicKey()   { return _PublicKey;  }
}
```

Comment: What is "jargon"? If there aren't any exceptions then you're getting your key back.

Comment: If I try and print the key its blank, but the length says 32. Then when I pass it along to the AES class to try and decrypt something I just get nonsense back is what I mean by jargon.

Comment: Please define how the data was encrypted and how the ciphertext is laid out. Where is the actual data ciphertext that is encrypted with AES? Where is the RSA ciphertext which contains the AES key? How were both encrypted?

Comment: We have a key file and an IV file. Both of them are encrypted with a public RSA key. The private RSA key is stored in a yaml file. Load the RSA private key into a string. Then trying to decrypt the key or IV file with the private RSA key. The AES part is not important its getting to the keys needed for AES thats the problem which is the RSA encrypted files.

Comment: You ignore the amount of bytes returned by the read in `dis.read(decryptedData);` How many bytes is returned?

Comment: Note that `CipherInputStream` helpfully ignores padding errors, something that is very stupid (this has to do with Java exception handling, a stream is only supposed to throw `IOException`). So basically you just don't get any data if decryption fails.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen its returning a -1

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen its returning 32 now I forgot to remove a base64 decrypt from the encrypted file it didn't need that. Still doesn't resolve my problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCE jars where in the wrong directory worked just fine once they got put in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

RSA can only encrypt a small amount of data which must be processed as a chunk. You don't need a stream for that. Simply call

```
byte[] aesKey = _pkCipher.doFinal(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(in));
```

to get the AES key.

Comment: So this is the route I went initially. And I get this error.
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:354) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0]

Comment: I forgot to pass the encrypted key into the decryption method. If this doesn't work, how was the AES key encrypted? Was really PKCS1Padding used or was OAEP used?

Comment: I get the error with passing in the byte array. Its what I was going initially. The private key was originally generated with ruby same with everything else. Private key: `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048).to_s.each_line.collect { |line| "    #{line}" }.join('')`

Comment: Please show how the AES key was encrypted, not how the RSA key was generated - edit it into the bottom of the question.

Comment: No, not needed as far as I know. @ is not required for the original poster or for the answerer. Darn, now I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: So it was all done by a third party library in ruby. The key pair is just a key and an IV that gets automatically and randomly generated thats what gets encrypted by the RSA public key. Im starting to miss ruby.
```rsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_rsa_key)


File.open(key_filename, 'wb') {|file| file.write( rsa_key.public_encrypt(key_pair[:key]) ) }```